# Can I use mono64 with Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: c#, mono, visual-studio-mac, aleagpu

I'm new to Mono development (but not .NET development) - got as far as downloading Visual Studio for Mac and trying to run a sample solution from Alea GPU. It complains that it needs mono64, but I see no option for selecting 64 bit architecture like I would in Windows, and Googling the issue has not turned up an answer I can make sense of. Can I use mono64 in VS for Mac and if so, how?

Comment: Close voter, its about a programming tool and as per [faq] **is** on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are running within VS4M, you need to set the architecture of the run configuration that you are using.

Using an ML (Alea-based) program that I wrote as an example:

#### Within VS4M:

- Open the Project Options and go to `Run / Configuration / Default`:

[image]

- Open the `Mono runtime settings` and set the Arch to 64-bit:

[image]

#### From the cmd-line:

Mono is 64-bit by default now, so you can run either:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/mono MovieMadnessComputeBoxOffice-Alea.exe
```

or

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/mono64 MovieMadnessComputeBoxOffice-Alea.exe
```

**Note:** On older version of Mono you would have to have used `mono --arch=64 ...`. If you need arch32, you use `mono32`, but CUDA only has 64 libs so this would not be needed for Alea usage.

Comment: Works! Though now I get "System dll not found" for libcuda.dylib. Seeing as you've used Alea before, any clue what that's about? Obviously a missing dll, but Alea claims you only need to install Alea via NuGet...

Comment: @seesharper I have no idea what that error would be... *Assuming* `System dll` would be referring the .Net assembly System.dll.... You could try to flag the project references with `Local Copy` (right-click on the each System.* project reference), but I do not have it set that way.... If that does not work, post another question with the full exception/stacetrace and include the tag `aleagpu`

Comment: I did it but inside Build -> Compiler, I only see x86 as the platform still!

Comment: I'm trying this (since obviously 32-bit mono no longer works on Catalina), but my Run Configuration panel has no "General" and "Advanced" tabs.  It has only a listbox with columns "Solution Item" and "Run Configuration".  No amount of clicking, double-clicking, or right-clicking brings up a screen like your image.  Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I got mine to work by setting the Project -> Options 
to run with 32 bit mono.
it all works, see pics.
[image]