# MonoDevelop - running application in 32-bit

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I have an application that I have developed for Windows and took the source code into Linux to run it there using MonoProject. I open the project and run it successfully. However, my project is using 32-bit libraries and I need to compile and run my program as a 32-bit application.

I'm setting the `Platform target` to `x86` as in the following screenshot:
[image]

I have the following code which verifies how the program is running:

```
    if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("running in 32-bit");
    }
    else if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("running in 64-bit");
    }
```

Even when setting `Plaform target` to `x86` is still show as "running in 64-bit".

How can I make it run in 32-bits?

Comment: Not sure if it is related, but at the mono download page, you have avaliable 32 and 64 bits runtime.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45874421/4984832

Comment: @bradbury9 No such download option for Linux - it's installed via `apt`

Comment: @SushiHangover - Not a relevant post as the options in the comment you refereed to do not exist/changed in the current version